# Magento custom module with custom database table admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I wants to view your custom table datas in admin panel

Comment: try to "google" magento module creator. Maybe module from @Marius  can help you https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9/wiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code is simple method to view your custom table datas in admin panel
Admin view for your custom module :

Create the below path in your module :

/app/code/local///etc/adminhtml.xml

in adminhtml.xml file contain below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <[module] module="[module]">
        <title>[Module]</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
        <children>
            <items module="[module]">
                <title>Manage Items</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>[module]/adminhtml_[module]</action>
            </items>
        </children>
    </[module]>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <[module]>
                    <title>[Module] Module</title>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                </[module]>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>   
</acl>
<layout>
    <updates>
```

Create the Adminhtml folder and create Controller.php file

/app/code/local///controllers/Adminhtml/Controller.php

in Controller.php file contain below content

```
<?php 
class <Namespace>_<module>_Adminhtml_<module>Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

public function indexAction()
{
        $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('<module>/items');
        $this->renderLayout();

}   

}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/.xml

in .xml file contain below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<[module]_adminhtml_[module]_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="domain" template="[module]/[module].phtml"/>
    </reference>
</[module]_adminhtml_[module]_index>
</layout>
```

Create the new folder in below path

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template//.phtml

in .phtml file contain below content

```
<?php

// Write your custom table Collection Here

?>
```